# wss undefined on server side configuration

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, server, wss

I need help with fixing the issue I'm facing.
On my server side I'm configuring websocket I have two files server.js and nftController.js below is the code. on nftController wss is undefined.

**server.js**

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = require("./app");
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });


process.on("uncaughtException", err=>{
  console.log("uncaughtException Shutting down Application");
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});

dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const DB = "mongodb+srv://rameez:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.ogku096.mongodb.net/NFTMarketplace?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: false,
  })
  .then((con) => {
    console.log("DB Connection Successfully");
  }) 

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('New WebSocket connection');
});


//console.log("wss", wss);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}....`);
});

process.on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
  console.log("unhandledRejection Shutting down Application");
  console.log(err.name, err.message); 
  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});

module.exports = { wss };
```

**nftController.js**

```
const { wss }  = require("../server");
const NFT = require("./../models/nftModel");
const APIFeatures = require("./../Utils/apiFeatures");
const catchAsync = require("../Utils/catchAsync");
const AppError = require("../Utils/appError");

console.log("wss", wss);

// Update top 5 NFTs data whenever there is new data
exports.aliasTopNFTs = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.limit = "5";
  req.query.sort = "-price";
  req.query.fields = "name,price,seller,image,createAt";
  const features = new APIFeatures(NFT.find(), req.query)
    .filter()
    .sort()
    .limitFields()
    .pagination();
  const nfts = await features.query;
  req.query.nfts = nfts;
  next();
});

const sendUpdatedData = (data) => {
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'UPDATE_DATA', data: data }));
    }
  });
}

exports.getAllNfts = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const features = new APIFeatures(NFT.find(), req.query)
    .filter()
    .sort()
    .limitFields()
    .pagination();
  const nfts = await features.query;
  sendUpdatedData(nfts);
  console.log("WSSdata", nfts);

  //SEND QUERY
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    results: nfts.length,
    data: {
      nfts,
    },
  });
});
```

i have checked exporting and importing wss alsofile path of server in nftController looks fine to me